# How to use ambassador as API gateway for Rails and Angular Application

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, ambassador

I have microservice based application. Backend built using Rails and Frontend built using Angular. Wanted to implement [Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/) as API gateway. Looked at documentation [here](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/) but not clear at all. I am deploying by using Helm charts. Dire need of help.

Comment: Have you deployed the ambassador?

Comment: What have you deployed with the helm chart ? your service or the ambassador?

Comment: Have only deployed backend services of application. After that got stuck with with ambassador and frontend

Comment: can you give more detail about your problem. is it on your installation or configuration?

Comment: Now I am confused how to expose frontend

Comment: You just need to deploy the frontend deployment.yaml and service.yaml for exposing your service